# LPC1343 Firmware Loading - Change drive label

Tags: arm, lpc, nxp

I have a system that is using the built-in firmware loading facility of the LPC1343.  When the flash drive is mounted, the disk is always labeled "CRP_DISABLED". Is there a way to change the label of the drive to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This label is in ROM, and cannot be modified as far as I know. Only NXP can change this in their production process - but they need good reason `($$$$$)` to do this.

The only thing you could do is to write your own boorloader. But given the small RAM (8k) and Flash (32k) of the device, this will be problematic, too - unless you have much space free in Flash.

Comment: I figured this was probably the case. Now it is confirmed!

Answer (score 1):

In the boot mode, the ROM will determine what the volume label will be when entering USB-ISP.  According to the manual, the volume label will reflect the state of the code-protection bits (CRP).  Seeing "CRP_DISABLED" means that the chip has not been code-protected, and you can read and/or write the flash memory.  Seeing any other volume label means that there is some level of code protection.  (Read the user-manual for information on these).

Also, note that due to a bug in some versions of the USB-ISP, you may have to wait for a second "connect" retry from the device, which can take around 15 seconds.  (This is documented in the user-manual).

Another thing-- if you use anything other than a Windows machine, you are going to have problems.  Windows writes sectors to disk drives on a "first available cluster" basis-- so, your firmware file will be written onto the device in the expected sequential order.  On non-Windows OS's, files are *NOT* written to "first available cluster" basis-- the files are written in (seemingly) random order.  This is the case with any of the *BSD's, Linux, and Apple OS/X (which is based on OpenBSD).  I can't remember why they do this-- maybe security or performance reasons-- but that doesn't matter, because if you erase the "firmware.bin" file, you will need a Windows machine to write it back. (Or, if you have the "mtools" package available for installation with your O/S, "mcopy" can write this file without any issues).  Another way to deal with non-Windows OS's in this situation-- If you don't first DELETE the file (like the user-manual suggests), your non-windows OS can open the file for writing, then copy the new firmware to the open file-- this will use the "clusters" (flash sections) in the same order as they originally appeared-- in sequential order.

But anyway, sorry-- no, you can't change the volume-label on the USB-ISP-MSD.

Comment: Great to know.  We had a user have an issue with the bootloader on OS X.  I thought it was a software issue as he had been running an older version of the firmware and upgraded to a new version with different configuration settings.  This is the reason, and sounds like we'll need to create a custom tool for loading the FW on OS X.

Answer (score 0):

The LPC1343 has USB drivers in ROM but you can change the descriptors. It is documented in the User Manual: http://www.nxp.com/download/pip/LPC1343FHN33/user_manual

Comment: To clarify, this is for the firmware loading facility, not the onboard USB mass storage driver.

Comment: Well, that was what you asked about.